# Unable to install TeX Live using Bash script

Tags: bash, debian

I am trying to install TeX Live inside a Jetbrains Datalore virtual machine. On first boot the vm automatically executes a script file `init.sh` that can be edited/uploaded through Datalore GUI.

This is my `init.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

# This shell script runs when the machine starts, 
# before the user-installed packages are set up.
#
# Use it to install additional dependencies.
#
# Examples:
#
# sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y some-package
#
# pip install some-package --additional-arguments
#
# The logs are stored in /tmp/log;
# the error log is copied to Notebook files.

#!/bin/bash

# This shell script runs when the machine starts, 
# before the user-installed packages are set up.
#
# Use it to install additional dependencies.
#
# Examples:
#
# sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y some-package
#
# pip install some-package --additional-arguments
#
# The logs are stored in /tmp/log;
# the error log is copied to Notebook files.

#!/bin/bash

# This shell script runs when the machine starts, 
# before the user-installed packages are set up.
#
# Use it to install additional dependencies.
#
# Examples:
#
# sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y some-package
#
# pip install some-package --additional-arguments
#
# The logs are stored in /tmp/log;
# the error log is copied to Notebook files.

sudo apt update -y &&
sudo rm -rf tmp_latex/
sudo mkdir tmp_latex &&
cd tmp_latex &&
sudo wget https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz &&
sudo tar -xf install-tl-unx.tar.gz --no-same-owner &&
sudo rm install-tl-unx.tar.gz &&
cd install-tl-* &&
sudo wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/prenone/bebaa5db68dd3e458dccbcefeb596bf3/raw/5e5590abffccbea76f69881fa3ce771d56912013/texlive.profile &&
sudo ./install-tl -profile texlive.profile -no-interaction &&
sudo tlmgr init-usertree &&
sudo tlmgr install amsmath &&
sudo tlmgr install cm-super &&
sudo tlmgr install underscore &&
sudo tlmgr install type1cm &&
sudo tlmgr install dvipng &&
sudo apt install dvipng -y &&
cd ../.. &&
sudo rm -rf tmp_latex/
```

When I ran each command from the shell separately everything works fine and TeX Live is installed successfuly along with the required packages. However when the script executes on boot I get the following error log

```
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

--2023-03-25 13:28:22--  https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz
Resolving mirror.ctan.org (mirror.ctan.org)... 5.35.249.60
Connecting to mirror.ctan.org (mirror.ctan.org)|5.35.249.60|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/ctan.org/tex/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz [following]
--2023-03-25 13:28:22--  https://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/ctan.org/tex/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz
Resolving ftp.heanet.ie (ftp.heanet.ie)... 193.1.193.10, 2001:770:18:aa40::c101:c10a
Connecting to ftp.heanet.ie (ftp.heanet.ie)|193.1.193.10|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 5737490 (5.5M) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘install-tl-unx.tar.gz’

     0K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0% 19.6M 0s
    50K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  1% 11.8M 0s

# ... more wget progress output ...

5550K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 99% 79.8M 0s
  5600K ...                                                   100% 21.7M=0.1s

2023-03-25 13:28:22 (37.0 MB/s) - ‘install-tl-unx.tar.gz’ saved [5737490/5737490]

--2023-03-25 13:28:24--  https://gist.githubusercontent.com/prenone/bebaa5db68dd3e458dccbcefeb596bf3/raw/5e5590abffccbea76f69881fa3ce771d56912013/texlive.profile
Resolving gist.githubusercontent.com (gist.githubusercontent.com)... 185.199.111.133, 185.199.108.133, 185.199.109.133, ...
Connecting to gist.githubusercontent.com (gist.githubusercontent.com)|185.199.111.133|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 933 [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘texlive.profile’

     0K                                                       100% 49.0M=0s

2023-03-25 13:28:24 (49.0 MB/s) - ‘texlive.profile’ saved [933/933]

./install-tl: could not run ./tlpkg/installer/config.guess, cannot proceed, sorry at tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 372.
```

If I try to run the file manually (after it has already been executed automatically by Datalore) `sudo bash init.sh` I get a different error and it seems like ./install-lt does not even output

```
# ...

texlive.profile                  100%[=======================================================>]     933  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2023-03-25 13:31:31 (4.39 MB/s) - ‘texlive.profile’ saved [933/933]

sudo: tlmgr: command not found
```

Comment: but if this is a debian, why make it so complicated? You can install texlive simply through apt: `sudo apt install -y texlive`, done. No need to manually download things!

Comment: I managed to install TeX Live and the packages I need that way, but I would rather be able to use `tlmgr`, which for some reasons (error regarding version) does not seem to work right out of the box. So thank you for the idea, but I'll leave the question open for now :D